# ExtJs5 override losing the listeners

Tags: extjs5, sencha-cmd

I have the following override in myPackage\overrides\window\Window:

```
Ext.define('myPackage.window.Window', {
    override: 'Ext.window.Window',

    listeners: {
        beforeshow: function (window) {
            console.log('before show');
        }
    }
});
```

I then use this with this code:

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.login.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    xtype: 'login',

    requires: [
        'myApp.view.login.LoginController',
        'Ext.form.Panel'
    ],

    controller: 'login',

    title: 'Login',

    closable: false,
    autoShow: true,
    resizable: false,

    listeners: {
        show: function() {
            console.log('in show');

        }
    },

    items: {
       ... snipped for brevity; a couple of textfields and a button
       ...
    }
});
```

The problem is that while the 'show' event in 'myApp.view.login.Login' works fine, the 'beforeshow' event in the override ('myPackage.window.Window') never fires.

If I then remove the listeners from 'myApp.view.login.Login', then the 'beforeshow' event in 'myPackage.window.Window' will then fire (I can see all this with the console.log output).

What I don't understand is, why? I am probably missing something fairly simple.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should add the listener after you window is initialized.
I haven't tested it yet. but I am sure it should solve your issue.

eg:

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.login.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    xtype: 'login',

    requires: [
        'Ext.form.Panel'
    ],

    title: 'Login',
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    closable: true,
    autoShow: true,
    resizable: false,
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        Ext.apply(me, {
            listeners: {
                show: function () {
                    console.log('in show');

                }
            },

            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    width: 300
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```